# Android: What is the Facebook app utilizing for ProgressDialog/Loading

Tags: android, facebook, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Check this screenshot here: http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5174/5389868759_8021dedbb8.jpg

What are they utilizing to do that while loading the data?  I've got my own progress Dialog setup, but I like how Facebookes and other apps I've seen have it inegrated right into the app as opposed to a new pop-up window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/progressBar"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
/>
```

[More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Answer (score 0):

They are probably using [Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_PROGRESS) and [Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#progressbar).